# How to do fast query on String dataType in MongoDB, where values are of type double

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a field `contractValue` and other fields in a collection `contract` which is of type  `String` . It basically holds double value like 1200 or 1500 but at some places it may contain value like $1200 or $1500.

Sample data from collection:

```
{ ..
   ..
   contractValue: "1200", //This is the one stored as String. I need 
                          // to perform range query over it
   ..

   ..
 }

{ ..
   ..
   contractValue: "$1500",
   ..

   ..
 }
```

I have requirement where i need to fetch contracts based on contract values. Query can be like below:

```
{$and: [ {'contractValue': {$gt: 100}}, {'contractValue': {$lt: 1000 }}]}
```

This query is giving me wrong result. It is also giving me documents having contractValue like 1238999
Also I need to create indexes on `contractValue`

- Is it possible to create index on contract value , so that I can efficiently make range query, so that whenever making any query, it will do < or > on Index and will fetch exact set of documents, rather than making change in schema?
- How to handle values like $1200 in index, so index value just contain 1200 as integer
  rather than $1200

Comment: can you post some sample data of each flavor (string, double, 1238999)?

Comment: is 1238999 defined as a string and therefore should be excluded?

Comment: a possible answer posted. I do agree with R2D2 better to convert all the contractValue to number

Answer (score 1):

try this:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/TG3Y5tdh9aK

it assumes string data will be either a quoted number or a quoted number with "$" at the front

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "newContractValue": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$contractValue",
          "to": "double",
          "onError": {
            $toDouble: {
              "$substr": [
                "$contractValue",
                1,
                {
                  "$strLenCP": "$contractValue"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "newContractValue": {
            $gt: 100
          }
        },
        {
          "newContractValue": {
            $lt: 1000
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

---

This can be used to set a new `contractValueNew` field as number from the existing contractValue

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({})
.forEach(function(record) {
    
    if(record.contractValue.toString().substring(0, 1) == '$') {
        record.contractValueNew = NumberInt(parseInt(record.contractValue.substring(1, record.contractValue.length)));
    } else {
        record.contractValueNew = NumberInt(parseInt(record.contractValue))
    }
    
    db.getCollection('yourCollection').save(record)
})
```

Comment: Can you provide me query to update fieldType from String to Double in collection?

Comment: I added some javascript tested from robo 3t.
The javascript above sets it to a new field.  To update the existing field, just replace `contractValueNew` to `contractValue`.  I set it to  a new field so I can compare to existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
      db.collection.find({'contractValue': {$gt: 100, $lt: 1000 }})
```

Create index on contractValue , but convert all values as numbers ...

Comment: I dont want to convert contractValue as number in collection. Thats a problem

Comment: @KCS you do want to convert. You just don't realise it yet. If you need to preserve original value for any reason - add an extra field with numeric value. To make ranged queries you need to convert it anyway, so convert it on write once per document rather than once per query for all documents. It will also allow you to create a useful index.